# Location value returning null android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a user's location and I have this method

```
public Location getCurrentLocation() {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    return location; 
}
```

I have another method that will center a circle object based on the `location` variable's latitude and longitude in this method

```
private void loadMapResources() {
     userLocation = getCurrentLocation();
     //DRAW CIRCLE HERE
     if(userRadius != 0){
         Circle radiusCircle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude()))
        .radius(userRadius)
        .strokeWidth(4)
        .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6699"))
        .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#66F3F3F3"))
      );
         //SHOW USER ICON AT CURRENT LOCATION
         BitmapDescriptor userIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_user);
         googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("YOU ARE HERE")
                .icon(userIcon)
                .position(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude()))
                );
     }
}
```

Now this code has worked before on devices with and without GPS. Could anyone tell me why `userLocation` is throwing a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I ran into a problem like this before. It has to do with when you call Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);, it is returning null because whatever service actually get the location hasn't had time to find the user's location by the time you get to userLocation.getLatitude().

Comment: It is likely that locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); is null, use the debug view and watch your variables.

Comment: Take a look at this sample file http://drt.io/vdhci it has a working structure for when to call the location manager and when to fetch a location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind, that `getLastKnownLocation` can sometimes return `null` (for example, if provider is currently disabled or there is no last known location), so you should always check the result of this method:

```
Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (location == null){
    //handle this case
    //return location with some default coordinates, for example
}
return location;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. How do I assign default co-ordinates to a location variable?

Comment: @DanielD i think something like this will work: `Location location = new Location(provider); location.setLatitude(...); location.setLongitude(...);`

Comment: Thank you my friend :) you've made me realise the importance of failing gracefully. In your experience do devices with GPS in good coverage areas throw this NullPointer?

Comment: @DanielD no, it's not so common. Anyway, if you handle case of `null`, you don't need to worry about it